# localhost keeps pointing to live...?

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu

I have 2 sites on local.

i'm trying to work on both/either wordpress installations on local. then transfer my changes to live.

but my browser keeps redirecting me to site1.com - the live site.

i've set ...

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'https://site1.com', 'http://localhost/') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'https://site1.com', 'http://localhost/');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'https://site1.com','http://localhost/');
```

for both sites ie. option_value, 'https://site2.com' ... for site2 etc...

i've looked in /etc/hosts/ nothing there. I've removed .htaccess. Still nothing.

Even when i

```
a2dissite site1
```

and do a

```
a2ensite site2
```

And restart apache. I still get pointed to site1.com live.

I've also included these in wp-config.php of both sites...

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost/');
```

One of the sites is a gym site. and when i do a

```
http://localhost/semi-private-training
```

I get a 404...

what would make both sites redirect to site1.com live? I can't find anything of use in the logs.

thanks

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache and try from the guest window?

Comment: also do consider disabling all plugins, especially somethings related to force ssl redirecting

Answer (score 0):

using chrome incognito helped.

but what did the job was disabling the WordPress really-simple-ssl plugin...

```
mv wp-content/plugins/really-simple-ssl/ wp-content/plugins/really-simple-ssl-park/
```

so when i wanted to copy from git_repo to localhost in order to work on local I ran a...

```
rsync -aP --exclude=/home/dara/git_repos/mysite_git/wp-content/plugins/really-simple-ssl --exclude=/home/dara/git_repos/mysite_git/wp-config.php/ /home/dara/git_repos/mysite_git/ /var/www/mysite/
```

this copied everything from git to localhost except the wp-config.php file and the really-simple-ssl directory.

NB: Don't forget to put the wp-config.php file in .gitignore if you are working on WordPress...